# Editing the field definition of a work item type

Tags: c#, tfs

My question is about TFS work items - does the TFS API support editing work item type field definitions?  I need to make what is described in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400654(v=vs.110).aspx) but using the C# TFS API.

Clarification #1: In the "Bug" work item type I created a definition called "Customer" and added its value items by wizard.  Does the C# TFS API support editing or deleting items in that field?

Clarification #2: I can retrieve that values by using:

```
AllowedValuesCollection Collec = WorkItemStore.FieldDefinitions["Customer"].AllowedValues;
```

But the allowed values are Readonly without any public setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can export the definition via the Export method provided in the API (This method return a XML document for the definition) and then edit the content in the XML document. After you finish the modification, import the XML document via Import method.

Instruction about Export Method:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemtype.export.aspx

Instruction about Import Method:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemtypecollection.import.aspx

However, modify WIT definition via API is not an efficient way. It is better to use Power Tool Process Editor or witadmin command to import/export/edit WIT.

Comment: Thank For Help .. But The Import Method Raised Error "TF26085: Unknown constant with id NumberHere" .. The Error Is About The Tfs Client Cache .. I tried WorkItemStore.SyncToCache(); And WorkItemStore..RefreshCache(); Before Import But Also Doesn't Work .. Any Idea ?

Comment: Clean the caches manually. The cache folder locates at C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\cache. You may see several folders under Team Foundation folder like 4.0, 5.0, clean the cache file in all of them.